# let V be a vector space, T : V → V be a linear transformation. Prove that $T^2 = 0$ if and only if $R(T) \subset N(T)$.

Tags: linear-transformations

Attempt:

$T^2 = 0$ if and only if for all $v \in V$ , $0 = T^2(v) = T(T(v))$ if and
only if for all $v \in V , T(v) \in N(T)$ if and only if $R(T) \in N(T)$.

If the question were this instead:  Let $T : V \to V$ be a linear operator for a vector space $V$. Prove that $R(T) \subset N(T)$ if and only if $T^2 = 0$, would the proof above ^ stil be fine ?

Comment: The proof seems alright. In your first paragraph you use " $R(t)\in N(T)$. The correct way is to say $R(T)\subset N(T)$ which you have used  in the second paragraph. But is this the point of your question? It is not clear.

Comment: There is a typo. In the first paragraph,its supposed to be R(T)⊂N(T). Not the " element " sign.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any logical distinction 'twixt the two, so *both* proofs look fine to me.

That being said, I would likely frame the argument something like this:

Given that

$T^2 = 0, \tag 1$

suppose

$x \in R(T); \tag 2$

then

$\exists y \in V \mid x = T(y); \tag 3$

thus

$T(x) = T^2(y) = 0 \Longrightarrow x \in N(T); \tag 4$

thus we see that

$R(T) \subset N(T); \tag 5$

now assuming (5), we have

$\forall y \in V \; T^2(y) = T(T(y)); \tag 6$

since

$T(y) \in R(T), \tag 7$

from (5) we obtain

$\forall y \in V, \; T^2(y) = T(T(y)) = 0, \tag 7$

whence

$T^2 = 0; \tag 8$

Comment: I have a problem with this detailed style of proof. IMHO when statements are straightforward and proof involves very standard arguments presenting in this manner might make it sound too bombastic. Of course one can defend this by saying once one should learn this rigorous way and only after this a learner would know this is standard. But what the OP presented in the question itself meets the standard of rigour.  So *my view* is that this elaborate style should be avoided.